# Downloading Zip file from a webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, download

I am trying to download the zip, which we can also download by clicking on "SCARICA I DATI CSV" on this [webpage](http://storico.openbilanci.it/bilanci/san-leonardo-in-passiria-st-leonhard-in-passeier-comune-bz?year=2014&type=consuntivo&cas_com_type=cassa). I want to do this for 7000+ Italian municipalities by using beautiful soup.

Right now, I have the following code for one city/municipality:

```
city_name = "vandoies-vintl"
prov_name = "bz"

r = urllib.request.urlopen('http://storico.openbilanci.it/bilanci/' + city_name + "-comune-" + prov_name).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')

# this is where the code breaks. because the HTML body does not have any mention of "csv" whatsoever, which is weird.

csv = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class':'pull-right csv'})
csvlink = csv[0]['href']
urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://storico.openbilanci.it" + csvlink, city_name+".zip")
```

I can't find any mention of **csv** when checking using `print(soup)`. Could someone please help? Thanks!

The following code works.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re
import os
import urllib
import zipfile
import re

output_path = r"/Users/aartimalik/Dropbox/delphine-miscellaneous/italy/test"

munis = [("monale", "at"), ("portacomaro", "at")]

munis = pd.DataFrame(munis)

munis.columns = ['municipality_clean','prov_abb']

def remove_paren(string):
    return re.sub(r'\(.*\)', '', str(string))
munis['municipality_clean']= munis['municipality_clean'].apply(lambda x: remove_paren(x))
munis['municipality_clean'] = munis['municipality_clean'].str.strip()
munis = munis.replace(' ', '-', regex=True)
munis = munis.apply(lambda x: x.str.lower())

for i in range(0,len(munis)):
    city_name = munis.iloc[i]['municipality_clean']
    prov_name = munis.iloc[i]['prov_abb']
    
    try:
        r = urllib.request.urlopen('http://storico.openbilanci.it/bilanci/' + city_name + "-comune-" + prov_name).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
        csv = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class':'pull-right csv'})
        try:
            csvlink = csv[0]['href']
            urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://storico.openbilanci.it" + csvlink, city_name+".zip")
            #print('Downloaded and extracted zip for ' + city_name + ', ' + prov_name)
            print(str(i) + ". " + city_name+": success")
            scrapesuccess = scrapesuccess.append(munis.iloc[i])

            newfolder= output_path + "/" + city_name.capitalize()
            if not os.path.exists(newfolder):
                os.makedirs(newfolder)

            zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(output_path + "/" + city_name + ".zip", 'r')
            zip_ref.extractall(newfolder)
            zip_ref.close()

        except:
            scrapefail = scrapefail.append(munis.iloc[i])
            print(str(i) + ". " + city_name+": fail")
    
    except:
        scrapefail = scrapefail.append(munis.iloc[i])
        print(str(i) + ". " + city_name+": fail")
```

Comment: The URL in your example (http://storico.openbilanci.it/bilanci/Verona-comune-VR) returns Page Not Found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres an example of downloading the zip in memory and writing a city directory with all the csv files.

```
import urllib.request as request
from io import StringIO
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile

import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.url_root = "http://storico.openbilanci.it"
        self.city_name = kwargs.get("city_name")
        self.prov_name = kwargs.get("prov_name")

    def main(self) -> None:
        file_link = self.get_link()
        zipped_file = self.download_file(file_link)
        unzipped_files_mapping = self.unzip_file(zipped_file)
        self.write_files(unzipped_files_mapping)

    def get_link(self) -> str:
        url = f"{self.url_root}/bilanci/{self.city_name}-comune-{self.prov_name}"

        response = request.urlopen(url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")

        return soup.find_all("a", attrs={"class": "pull-right csv"})[0]["href"]

    def download_file(self, zip_link: str) -> str:
        url = f"{self.url_root}{zip_link}"

        return request.urlretrieve(url)[0]

    @staticmethod
    def unzip_file(file_handle: str) -> dict:
        zip_file_object = ZipFile(file_handle, "r")
        files = zip_file_object.namelist()

        return {
            file: pd.read_csv(StringIO(zip_file_object.open(file).read().decode("utf-8")), sep=";")
            for file in files
        }

    def write_files(self, file_mapping: dict) -> None:
        for file, df in file_mapping.items():
            file_path, file_name = file.rsplit("/", 1)
            path = Path(f"/path/to/files/{self.city_name}/{file_path}")
            path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
            df.to_csv(f"{path}/{file_name}")


city_name = "vandoies-vintl"
prov_name = "bz"
Scraper(city_name=city_name, prov_name=prov_name).main()
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to save the municipality-specific zip file to a specific folder? For example, I added `zip_ref = zip_file_object(output_path + "/" + city_name + ".zip", 'r')` (where `output_path` is defined in the preamble) to the code, but it returns the error `TypeError: 'ZipFile' object is not callable`

Comment: You just want save the zipped file to a specific location without unzipping?

Comment: Ideally, I would like to save the unzipped folder (which has multiple files) to a specific folder, but I'm not sure if that's possible. So, thinking about unzipping the folder after saving the zips first. Thank you.

Comment: Oh okay, I think I got it. I'm adding the code that works to my question. It saves both zipped and unzipped folders :) Thanks again.

Comment: Okay, it looks like it's only saving the zip files, haha. Trying to figure it out.

Comment: I updated the answer would that work?

Comment: I will check and let you know. I fear that it might only save the first CSV file from the unzipped folder, whereas we would want to save all the CSV files in various subfolders in this unzipped folder. But I'll check and confirm. Thank you.

Comment: The edit creates the directory paths for all csvs.